# Prove that any non-zero vector which is not a characteristic vector for $T$ is a cyclic vector for $T$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ be a linear operator on $F^2$. Prove that any non-zero vector which is not a characteristic vector for $T$ is a cyclic vector for $T$. Hence, prove that either $T$ has a cyclic vector or $T$ is a scalar multiple of the identity operator.

I have no clue how to prove any of the statements. Can I get some help getting started?

Answer (score 1):

If $v \ne 0$ is *not* an eigenvector (or "characteristic vector") for $T$, then

$Tv \ne 0 = 0 \cdot v, \tag 1$

since $Tv = 0$ asserts that $v$ is an eigenvector corresponding to $0$; also, $v$ and $Tv$ are linearly independent over $F$ (since here $F$ is our base field); if not, we have $a, b \in F$, not both $0$, with

$av + bTv = 0; \tag 2$

now here $b \ne 0$, lest

$av = 0 \Longrightarrow a = 0, \tag 3$

since $v \ne 0$; but then $a = b = 0$, contrary to hypothesis; likewise $a \ne 0$, else

$bTv = 0 \Longrightarrow Tv = 0, \tag 4$

which violates (1); so

$a \ne 0 \ne b, \tag 5$

and thus we may write

$Tv = -\dfrac{a}{b} v; \tag 6$

that is, $v$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $-a/b$, again a contradiction; so $v$ and $Tv$ are linearly independent over $F$; thus, since

$\dim_F F^2 = 2, \tag 7$

$F^2 = \text{span} \{ v, Tv \}; \tag 8$

that is, $v$ is cyclic for $T$.

Now suppose $T$ has no cyclic vector; then every $0 \ne v \in F^2$ is an eigenvector associated with some $\mu_v \in F$:

$Tv = \mu_v v, \; \mu_v \in F; \tag 9$

choosing $0 \ne w \in F^2$ linearly independent from $v$ we may write

$Tw = \mu_w w, \tag{10}$

whence

$T(v + w) = Tv + Tw = \mu_v v + \mu_w w; \tag{11}$

but also by assumption

$T(v + w) = \mu_{v + w}(v + w), \tag{12}$

and thus

$\mu_v v + \mu_w w = \mu_{v + w}(v + w) = \mu_{v + w}v + \mu_{v + w}w; \tag {13}$

it now follows from the linear independence of $v$ and $w$ that

$\mu_v = \mu_w = \mu_{v + w} = \mu \in F, \tag{14}$

and we conclude that

$Tv = \mu v = \mu I v, \; \forall v \in F; \tag{15}$

that is, $T = \mu I$ is a scalar multiple of the identity matrix $I$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Consider two cases:

1. $T$ has at least one eigenvector.
2. $T$ has no eigenvector.